# React Native - updating UI when in a loop using functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a React Native app and I have a process whereby I want to put a progress center or progress bar in the UI as it runs.

I found this code in SO but I'm not sure how to implement in my functional component.

Could please give me an example of how to call `ProgressBar` from my `func` component and how to increase progress value.?

Thanks in advance.

```
const ProgressBar = (props)=>{

    const [value] = useState(new Animated.Value(props.value))

    useEffect(()=>{
        Animated.timing(value, {
            toValue: props.value,
            duration: 100,
        }).start()
    }, [props.value])

    const width = value.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 100],
        outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
    })

    return (
        <View style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}>
            <Animated.View style={{
                width: width,
                height: '100%',
                backgroundColor: 'green',
            }}></Animated.View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check a fully working example with progress value change.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from "react-native";
import Slider from "@react-native-community/slider";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  const [value] = useState(new Animated.Value(props.value));

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(value, {
      toValue: props.value,
      duration: 100,
    }).start();
  }, [props.value]);

  const width = value.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: ["0%", "100%"],
  });

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        flexDirection: "row",
        backgroundColor: "white",
      }}
    >
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width: width,
          height: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "green",
        }}
      ></Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(10);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
        <Text> Change slider value to see progress bar follow </Text>{" "}
      </View>
      <View style={{ height: 20 }}>
        {" "}
        <ProgressBar value={progress} />{" "}
      </View>

      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
        <Slider
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={100}
          onValueChange={setProgress}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

Expo snack - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/30efea

Comment: What I wanted is to call a method in the App function that would run thru a loop and setting the progress value??

Comment: This is for the demo. I don't have a big picture of how your app works. You can react at me for a call at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com for further assistance

Answer (score 0):

Use setter to set the value

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(props.value)

useEffect(()=>{
    Animated.timing(value, {
        toValue: progress,
        duration: 100,
    }).start()
}, [progress])
```

to update progress bar, call `setProgress(newValue)`